# Can a type table of table%rowtype be indexed by some field of table%rowtype?

Tags: oracle, plsql

**Why to I asked this question?**

I have a table which as key that have a lot of field. Every time, I'm making a jointure, I miss a field. Therefore I have defined a pipelined function that take the key as an argument so that I am sure that I get only one element when I'm doing a jointure.
But the query take more time now. The table a has an index on some fields but not the table type used by pipelined function. I would like to know if it is possible to created a index on some fields of the table%rowtype

code:

```
create table a ( a1 integer);

create package p_a
as
   type t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE;
   
   function f(i_a1 integer) return t_a pipelined;
end;

CREATE PACKAGE BODY p_a
AS
    CURSOR c_A (i_a1 INTEGER)
        RETURN a%ROWTYPE
    IS
        SELECT t.*
          FROM a t
         WHERE t.a1 = i_a1;

    FUNCTION f (i_a1 INTEGER)
        RETURN t_a
        PIPELINED
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR c IN c_a (i_a1)
        LOOP
            PIPE ROW (c);
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;

with b as( select 1 b1 from dual) select * from b cross apply (table(p_a.f(b.b1)));
```

**the question**

I've tried to index the type table by a field of a table like this

```
create table a ( a1 integer);

create package p_a2
as
   type t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE index by a.a1%type;
   
   function f(i_a1 integer) return t_a pipelined;
end;
```

> PLS-00315: Implementation restriction: unsupported table index type

Is what I want to do possible. If not how to solve the performance problems mentioned in the  introduction?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1402c249cf944b5fbf7deec41a56ac0c)

Comment: As described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/collection-variable.html#GUID-89A1863C-65A1-40CF-9392-86E9FDC21BE9): *Specifies that the data type of the indexes of the associative array is a data type specified with either %ROWTYPE or %TYPE. This data type must represent **either** PLS_INTEGER, BINARY_INTEGER, or VARCHAR2(v_size)*

Comment: But after that you will have another issue: *The data type of the value that a pipelined table function returns must be a collection type defined either at schema level or inside a package (**therefore, it cannot be an associative array type**).* See [`RETURN datatype` section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-58D850B2-A416-47EA-8803-8936E2D6748A). Why do you want to use associative array for pipelined function's return type? It doesn't construct an entire collection before output, but works in a streaming mode

Comment: The 'index' here is also completely different to a table index - it is an PL/SQL index into the array (like `a[3]` in C etc.), not into the returned collection. It isn't being used within your PL/SQL code, and isn't going to have any performance benefit when you refer to the pipelined output. This seems like quite an odd construct all round - you are adding context switching and stopping the optimizer knowing the best way to join.

Comment: If you want the optimizer to use an index on a table, then you need to design the query in the way that will apply appropriate filters. But looks like a change to the list of indexed columns should change the query and therefore the function's signature, which is impossible without dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

A `TYPE` is **NOT** a table and cannot be indexed.

---

When you do:

```sql
create package p_a
as
   type t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE;
end;
/
```

You are defining a type and the type is a collection data type; an instance of that type is **NOT** a physical table and but is more like an in-memory array.

---

When you create a `PIPELINED` function:

```sql
function f(i_a1 integer) return t_a pipelined;
```

It does **NOT** return a table; it returns the collection data type.

---

When you do:

```sql
type t_a iS TABLE of a%ROWTYPE index by a.a1%type;
```

You are **NOT** creating an index on a table; you are changing to a different collection data type that is an associative array (like a JavaScript object or a Python dictionary) that stores key-value pairs.

An associative array is a PL/SQL data type and (with limited exceptions in later versions for insert, update and delete statements) cannot be used in SQL statements.

---

When you do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(p_a.f(1));
```

Then you are passing a collection data type to an SQL statement and the table collection expression `TABLE()` is treating the collection expression as if it was a table. It is still **NOT** a table.

---

If you want to use an index on the table then use the table (without a cursor or a pipeline function):

```sql
WITH b (b1) AS (
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT *
FROM   b
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT a.*
         FROM   a
         WHERE  a.a1 = b.b1;
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line of your question says it all:  "key that have a lot of field". If I understand correctly, the table has a primary key that consists of a large number of columns and because of that writing queries becomes a challenge.

It sounds like you're trying to do something pretty complex that should not be an issue at all.

Take a step back and ask yourself - does this *need* to be the primary key of the table ? Or can you use a surrogate key (identity column, sequence), use that as the primary key and just create a unique index on the set of field that currently make up the primary key. It will (1) simplify your data model and (2) make writing the queries a lot easier.